# Proftpd access.log and awstats fun

Tags: awstats

Had quite a bit of AWStats for one day. The AWStats LogFormat [docs](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_config.html#LogFormat) state that the following log line:

`[24/Sep/2009:17:15:12 -0500] x.x.x.x UNKNOWN xxxtemp "STOR recxxx.zip" 226 5164965`

should be matched by the following LogFormat:

`LogFormat="%time1 %host %other %logname %methodurlnoprot %code %bytesd"`

that is, if the `LogSeperator` is set to a single space (" "). But somehow it doesnt match, and I get a `AWStats did not find any valid log lines that match your LogFormat parameter` error every time. Has anyone had experience with this?

Comment: The format looks correct.
Are you sure those are really spaces?
How are you running AWstats? (as a cgi or from the cli)

Comment: As a script, "awstats_update.pl now". They are spaces indeed, put them there myself multiple times with vim! :/